# Display API data stored in array on frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am new to react and have written a functional component to call an API that stores data as an array that I defined called Measurments .

My problem is that I have not been able to display the Array data on my front end.

Can anyone provide any guidance on how to be able to display this on my web page?

I attempted to use the notation:

```
{ measurement[0].name }
```

in the return statement but it does not return anything.

I've also tried to assign them to the prop values **(parameter, unit, lastUpdated)** at the time the API is handling the data and that also didn't work.

```
    parameter = result[i].measurements[0].parameter;
    unit = result[i].measurements[0].unit;
    lastUpdated = result[i].measurements[0].lastUpdated;
```

I have attached the full contents of the file so you can see my logic.
This file is called ***CitySelection.js***

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
const measurements = [];
const CitySelection = (props) => {
    var city = props.city;
    var cityTwo = props.cityTwo;
    var parameter = props.parameter;
    var unit = props.unit;
    var lastUpdated = props.lastUpdated;

const Api_call = (city, cityTwo) => {
    let api = "https://u50g7n0cbj.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/latest?limit=100&page=1&offset=0&sort=asc&radius=1000&country_id=US&country=US&city="+city.city+"&city="+cityTwo.cityTwo
    axios.get(api, { crossdomain: true })     
    .then(response => {    
    var result = response.data.results
    
    // This is where measurments *Array* gets populated
    if (result != null){    
        for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++){     
            parameter = result[i].measurements[0].parameter;
            lastUpdated = result[i].measurements[0].lastUpdated;
            unit = result[i].measurements[0].unit;
            console.log(unit, parameter, lastUpdated);
            measurements.push({
            "name":result[i].city, 
            "value":result[i].measurements[0].value,
            "unit":result[i].measurements[0].unit, 
            "parameter":result[i].measurements[0].parameter,
            "lastUpdated":result[i].measurements[0].lastUpdated
        })   
      }
    
    }

})
} 
    return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => Api_call({city},{cityTwo})} >Compare Air Quality </button>
                     <p>{ measurements[0].name }</p>

                <span>{unit} {parameter} {lastUpdated}</span>
                <a>{city} has metrics for {parameter}{unit} and this dated was collected: {lastUpdated}</a>
           
        </div>
    )
}

export default CitySelection;
```

Comment: You need to store `measurement` as a state value so the component re-renders when it is update

Comment: React is a lot different from normal JS. It's a library that updates the DOM based on "state". And you have to define state in your component. For example, [`var measurements = []` should be `const [measurements, setMeasurements] = useState([]);`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). It may be helpful [to review the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) so you understand how React works.